# Redundancy notice for less than two years of employment (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

It hasn't been 100% confirmed in writing, but my boss has told our team verbally, that due to the lack of work in our backlog, we wont be able to sustain all of us, and that one of us will likely go in quarter 1 of 2016.

As a result, I have been trying to look into my redundancy rights. I am currently employed in the UK, and joined 20th April 2014. So my two year work anniversary will be 20th April 2016.

Due to the fact my boss said it will be likely the first quarter if it did happen, what are my rights for redundancy in terms of pay and notice.

On my contract it states:

> Once you have completed your probationary period, this notice period will increase to one month's written notice on either side...

Online though, it states:

> At least 1 week - if you have been employed continuously by your employer for more than 1 month but less than 2 years.

So is my notice under redundancy 1 week or 1 month.

Thanks for any answers and any advice you feel may be useful or any knowledge of the law which I can use for my own empowerment.

Comment: What do you mean by "Online though, it states..." Is that a website of your company?

Comment: @gnasher729 when searching on Google, for example on external websites and gov websites.

Comment: @RSM. In that case, it'd be better to give an actual source.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, depending on the company size, the boss will not be able to just give you notice. There may be a consultation process legally required, to determine who will be laid off.

Some details here: https://www.gov.uk/redundant-your-rights

If you read about "statutory rights", that is the minimum rights that you have no matter what your contract says. If your contract has better conditions, then the contract counts.

Comment: The "consultation period" may have started in as much as he has given you a verbal message to the fact.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The company size is perhaps 3000, and the team is a small team of 3 that is under threat. So the longer period is the one that counts? Although my contract just says notice in a general term, it doesnt mention redundancy specifically.

Comment: @Soren: Can't see any evidence of consultancy period. If it's not in writing, it doesn't count anyway. RSM: In a company of 3,000 there will be a strong obligation to find you a different position in the company. That's what the consultancy period is about. Did anyone give you a list of other available positions at the company? And notice period applies to anything.

Comment: *the boss will not be able to just give you notice* - OMG - that's horrible... *"We don't have any business, no customers, no work, no money in the bank and yet we cannot fire you"* - Silicon Valley has much more lenient employment law...

Comment: @MichalStefanow: What makes you say OMG - that's horrible? It's excellent. A company with 3,000 employees cannot just dump you. They have to try to find a different position in the company for you and offer it to you first. What's horrible about that?

Comment: @gnasher729 *"it's excellent"* - to whom? That makes hiring a daunting task... Easy to say "yes" costly to get divorce.